# Confidence Interval for Markov Chain Probability

Tags: confidence-interval, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process

I have a simple transition model I am trying to use to predict the probability of two states.

$$ 
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 p_{1,t+1}\\
 p_{2,t+1} \\
 \end{bmatrix}=
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 p_{11} & p_{12} \\
 p_{21} & p_{22} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 p_{1,t}\\
 p_{2,t} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

I compute $p_{1,t+1},p_{1,t+2},p_{1,t+3},p_{1,t+4...}$ the predicted probability of a state I am interested for $T$ periods out in the future. How do I compute the prediction confidence interval for such a probability $p_{1,t+1}$?

From what I understand the probability $p$ is binomial distributed and would have the following confidence interval. But I am unsure what $n$ would be in this confidence interval, if it indeed it was the correct confidence interval. My data is panel ($i$ individuals, and $T$ time periods), so I am not sure what $n$ would be.

$$\hat{p}\pm z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$$

Comment: What do you observe and how do you estimate $p_{1,t+1}$?

Comment: I estimate it based on the transition from the last state. It's the predicted value. That's what the transition matrix is doing, it's calculating $p_{1,t+1}$

Comment: You are asking for a confidence interval for the *future probabilities,* not the transition matrix elements, right?  And as far as the matrix goes, where does that come from?  Is it assumed, or--as suggested by your post--*estimated* from observing some transitions?  And if so, surely you already know how many transitions you have observed, so in asking about what $n$ to use you must be concerned about some complication--but what would it be?

Comment: Yes, I am asking about the confidence interval for the future probabilities. Even though I observe a lot of transitions for many individuals (i=30,000) , I don't have a large number of time periods, T=10. So I feel for my confidence interval n=10, to account for the uncertainty I have over time.

Comment: great question - following!